# Tags don't work properly today

Tags: bug, status-completed

I have faced  some problems today when tried to filter questions by tags:

On Stack Overflow when I click on Unanswered > Android Tag, for example, and then newest, I get questions tagged with C#, c++ or something like that, but no android tags.

Is that a bug? If not, what causes this strange behaviour?

[image]

Comment: looking right now; and hands up: this is certainly something I've done. Checking.

Comment: can you provide an example URL? because `http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/android?tab=newest` seems to be working OK

Comment: ah, never mind - it is me; looks like a cache bug; checking...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/android

Comment: The Filter don't work for all the Tags not only Android one

Comment: I always Get question tagged with C#

Comment: k; all servers deployed - is it ok now?

Comment: yes it's Fixed, thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cache bug, related to changing the internal implementation of something... not very interesting *what*, but: bug, my bad. Fix is deploying currently. Just need to wait for it to churn through the various environments (and a quick validation etc).

Comment: Is every cache bug your fault?

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn no, but my name appears against all of them due to a cache bug

Comment: You seem resigned to it :(

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn what can I say; I tend to get involved in a lot of deep-under-the-bonnet crazy tag-querying code. This has lots of highly parallel threading, caching, and cross-server APIs.